# Angular, property does not exist on type

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a small weather app. All works fine in browser, but I'm getting errors from TS compiler:  property `name`, `main`, `wind` does not exist on type `Weather[]`. But seems like I added these properties in class `Weather[]`...

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {  
  weather:Weather[];
  temp:string;
  pressure:number;
  humidity:number;
  wind_speed:number;
  wind_dec:number;
  city:string;
  activeId:string = "Misto Kyyiv"; 

  constructor(private getWeatherService:GetWeatherService) {}

  ngOnInit() {    
    this.getWeatherService.getWeather("Misto Kyyiv").subscribe(weather => {
      this.weather = weather;
      this.temp = (weather.main.temp -273.15).toFixed(2);
      this.pressure = weather.main.pressure;
      this.humidity = weather.main.humidity;
      this.wind_speed = weather.wind.speed;
      this.wind_dec = weather.wind.deg;
      this.city = weather.name;
      console.log(this.weather);
      console.log(this.temp);
    });
  }
```

```
export class Weather {
    main:any = {};
    wind:any = {};
    temp:number;
    pressure:number;
    humidity:number;
    wind_speed:number;
    wind_dec:number;
    city:string;
    activeId:string; 
    name:string;   
}
```

```
  //Get Weather 
  //it worked when I changed here Weather[] to Weather !!!
  getWeather(city:string):Observable<Weather> {
    let key = "c2dcf8ffb5cdc3f8977bfd2ae7ea4738";    
    let url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + "&?units=metric&APPID=" + key;
    return this.http.get<Weather>(url);
  }
```

Comment: The type `Weather[]` is not the type `Weather`. It's the type of an **array** of Weather objects. An array has a length. But it doesn't have a name or a wind.

Comment: okey... and how can I fix this?

Comment: I don't know, because the code doesn't make much sense to me, and I can't deduce what it should do by just looking at the code. Is `getWeather("Misto Kyyiv")` supposed to provide **one** Weather object, or an array of 0 to N Weather objects? If it's supposed to provide just one, then its signature, and probably its code, should be fixed. If it's supposed to provide an array, then what are you supposed to do with the elements of this array?

Comment: change  declaration weather:Weather[] to  weather:Weather.
Also when you subscribe, you can implicitly tell response type obs.subscribe((weather: Weather) => { // do something});

Comment: @JBNizet has right concern. Please provide what service returns.

Comment: Yes, ```getWeather("Misto Kyyiv")``` is supposed to get one object according to city name - ```"Misto Kyyiv"```. And I just need to grab some keys/values from it (like temperature, pressure, wind...).

Comment: It worked when I changed in Get request ```Weather[]``` to ```Weather```. Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed `Weather[]` to `Weather`, and TS compiler stopped yelling!

Comment: Aren't  you the savior!.

Answer (score 2):

Try defining `data:any` in `subscribe`

```
ngOnInit() {    

    this.getWeatherService.getWeather("Misto Kyyiv").subscribe((data: any)=> {
      this.weather = data;
      this.temp = (data.main.temp -273.15).toFixed(2);
      this.pressure = data.main.pressure;
      this.humidity = data.main.humidity;
      this.wind_speed = data.wind.speed;
      this.wind_dec = data.wind.deg;
      this.city = data.name;
      console.log(this.weather);
      console.log(this.temp);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and just that was the solution.
Before:

```
async getProfessional(){
     await this._ps.getProfessional(idProfessional).subscribe( data => {
        this.professionalSkills = data[0].aptitudes;
        this.technicalSkills = data[0].technologies;

    });
  }
```

After:

```
async getProfessional(){
     await this._ps.getProfessional(idProfessional).subscribe( (data:any) => {
        this.professionalSkills = data[0].aptitudes;
        this.technicalSkills = data[0].technologies;
    });
  }
```